# Can one instruction on x86 be split across a page boundary?

Tags: x86, instructions

Can an instruction could be located on multiple pages like... half of the instruction(some bytes consisting that instructions) is located on page A, the rest located on page B?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, parts of the same instruction can be located in two adjacent pages of memory.

Comment: Okay thanks. BTW what happens when those two code pages containing that instruction is not loaded on the physical memory?? It should occurs page fault right? At this time would page fault be occured two times? And how the page table maintains the mapping of that virtual memory?

Comment: @JaeHyukLee Both pages must be mapped at the same time. If either of them or both are not mapped, you get a page fault. Page tables don't maintain anything other than their state. It's the OS that must alter them appropriately to ensure there's forward progress. (it should be possible to control mapping within your own application by that same application, but that's uncommon).

Comment: Okay thanks. but what do you mean by "Page tables don't maintain anything other than their state" ? you mean whether it is loaded on the physical memory?

Comment: @JaeHyukLee They are just tables. They don't do anything. They just exist. The CPU reads them. The OS reads and writes them.