# Is that possible for an instruction to be split into different physical pages?

Tags: linux, memory-management, virtual-memory

For example, an instrution has 7 bytes, the former 4 bytes are mapped into page A, and it's the last 4 bytes of that page. Then the latter 3 bytes are mapped into another page B. A and B are not continious.
Is this possible? If yes, how does the CPU fetch this instruction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986984/can-one-instruction-on-x86-be-split-across-a-page-boundary

Comment: On most RISC archs it's not a thing.

Comment: @tink Dose it  mean that cpu will fetch such instruction with 2 tries, 4 bytes first then 3 bytes?